# grep a csv file using as input another csv or txt file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, grep

I have two csv files:

The first one, let's call it file1.csv, has the information that I need and it's something like:

```
Cell,Bitrate,Loss Ratio,Retransmitted Ratio
MI456,400,0.6,2.3,....
MI457,400,0.6,2.3,...
MI458,400,0.6,2.3,...   
.
.
.
```

The second one, file2.csv,has the subset of cells I need to extract from file1, and it is something like this:

```
Cell
MI400
CA500
VE600
```

And I want my output to be:

```
Cell,Bitrate,Loss Ratio,Retransmitted Ratio
MI400,400,0.6,2.3,....
CA500,400,0.6,2.3,...
VE600,400,0.6,2.3,...
```

I've trying to use:

```
cat file1.csv | grep -f file2.csv
```

or
    grep -f

but without success, could you please help me?

I'm using Linux 2.6.31.2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: How many elements are there in file2.csv?

Comment: Will that input generate that exact output? Or are you using that I/O as an example of your files only?

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html

Comment: In file1.csv there are about 100k rows and in file2.csv 5k rows.

Comment: The output generated should be something very similar, the difference is that file1.csv has about 450 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $1 in a' file2.csv file1.csv
```

Comment: It gives me nothing. I would have post the files but file1 is 200MB.

Comment: I think that what is causing the problem is the fact that in file1.csv there are no spaces. fields are separated with ",".

Comment: No, that is not the problem, the script handles that with `-F,`. Do you have spaces at the end of your lines in file1.csv? Was either file created in DOS and so has spurious control-Ms? Try `head file | cat -v` on each file to see if control characters are lurking.

Comment: Solved!. The problem was in file2.csv. I created a new one and now everything is working! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This will replace the first column in file1.csv with the contents of the file2.csv:

```
cut -d',' -f2- file1.csv | paste -d',' file2.csv -
```

Comment: I think he is trying to use file2 as query for file1, not as substitution (see my answer below).

Comment: This is exactly what I was just about to post as an answer when yours popped up. But after reconsideration, I think we kinda failed to notice the keywords "extract" and "subset" in the question. The user seems to in fact want to output every line of file1 that starts with any of file2 as its first field.

Comment: Yes, I want my output file to be as you just said. Now I will try to test the solutions posted. Many thanks to every one!

Answer (score 0):

```
for FOO in `cat file2.csv`; do
    grep "^$FOO" file1.csv
done
```

This will be very slow if file2.csv has lots of rows.

Comment: I'm an amateur so maybe this is a very silly question. Do I have to write the script directly in the bash?

Comment: @user1970421, just write it in bash.

Comment: You need a comma after FOO on the grep or it'd match MI45 against MI45 and MI456, etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are using the `-f` option in the wrong way

Here is an example:

file1:

```
Cell,Bitrate,Loss Ratio,Retransmitted Ratio
MI456,400,0.6,2.3,....
MI457,400,0.6,2.3,...
MI458,400,0.6,2.3,...
MI465,400,0.6,2.3,...
MI477,400,0.6,2.3,...
```

file2:

```
MI456
MI457
MI465
```

grep:

```
grep -f file2 file1
MI456,400,0.6,2.3,....
MI457,400,0.6,2.3,...
MI465,400,0.6,2.3,...
```

Comment: That would cause incorrect output in various situations, for example if MI4567 was present in file1 or MI456 could appear elsewhere in a line than just in the first field.

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo. I try to use it but without success, although as Ed said, this would be incorrect because there are cells named for example: MI45.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  sed 1q file1.csv
  join -t, <(sed 1d file1.csv | sort) <(sed 1d file2.csv | sort)
} > newfile.csv
```

`join` requires the input files to be sorted. I'm using `sed` to delete the header line inside the process substitutions.